# CSS alignment issues

Tags: css, browser, compatibility

I have been trying to build a website and when i was testing the website for browser compatibility issues on various browsers I noticed that there were problems with alignment.

Below is the live link for the HTML and CSS

http://jsfiddle.net/JaaNM/3/

> ```
> <ul id="service-ul-box">
> <li><a href="#">E-Learnin</a></li>
> <li><a href="#">LMS Help Desk</a></li>
> <li><a href="#">Content Management</a></li>
> <li><a href="#">Presentations</a></li>
> <li><a href="#">Content Development</a></li>
> <li><a href="#">Lecture Development</a></li>
> </ul>
> ```

The problem is, when I open the webpage with Mozilla Firefox it is fine. However when I execute the same script on Google Chrome the list item positioning is not correct. It either over laps or list items are not in a single row.

If I adjust the positioning according to Google Chrome, the positioning on Mozilla is not correct. and this happens vice versa.

On the whole what I am trying to explain is that the results that I get on Mozilla Firefox and Google Chrome are not the same.

I would like to know where am I going wrong.

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you 
Hareesh

Answer (score 0):

```
#service-ul-box li:last-child {
    border:none;
    float:right;
}
```

Not sure if that's the behavior you wanted, but this rule - float:right; - throws off the last element.

```
#service-ul-box li:last-child {
    border:none;        
}
```

Works, given that you have enough screen space.